# MySQL - How to join multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL Database with 3 tables: artists, genre and genre_artist. I need a MySQL-query which gives me all artists for a specific genre. Lets say "Rock". I'm not so experienced in joining MySQL tables, so can anyone help me out?

my table rows are as following:

artists:

```
artist_id (int, ai, pk)
artist_name(varchar)
artist_image(varchar)
```

genre:

```
id, (int, ai, pk)
name (varchar)
parent_id (int)
```

genre_artist:

```
genre_artist_id (int, ai, pk)
genre_id (int)
artist_id (int)
```

So, anyone who can help me out?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: _I'm not so experienced in joining_... Have you tried to write the query?  It would be very helpful to see your attempts because you might be incredibly close and all you need is a suggestion to get you the correct result.  Please edit your question with any attempts that you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT artists.*
FROM artists join genre_artist on genre_artist.artist_id = artists.artist_id
             join genre        on genre.id = genre_artist.genre_id and genre.name = 'Rock';
```

Comment: This is actually pretty good and I will accept this answer... only thing though is, that each artistname gets displayed, as how many albums they have, fexample when an artist has 5 albums, the artistname gts displayed 5 times... how can that be? I have an album table but obviously its not included in the query...

Comment: @SHT The query that I wrote will display multiple lines only if an artist has many genre_artist entries. I suppose that since you have this table, there is a many-to-many relationship between your artists and your genres. Hence one artist may have many genres and one genre may be associated to many artists. If that is the case, your design allows that this query brings the same artist multiple times. If that was not your intention, you probably need to change your db design.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM
    `artists` a
    INNER JOIN `genre_artist` ga ON ga.artist_id = a.artist_id
    INNER JOIN `genre` g ON g.genre_id = ga.genre_id
WHERE
    g.name = 'Rock'
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Let say you have the id of rock in `$genreId`, you could use a subquery

```
$genre_id = mysql_real_escape_string($genreId); // basic protection
$subquery = "SELECT artist_id FROM genre_artist WHERE genre_id = {$genre_id}";
$query = "SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artist_id IN ({$subquery})";
```

Joins can be very intent for the database. If you havent added the right indice and have thge tables in the wrong mode, you could lock tables longer then needed, which creates slow performance.
*Small note: Subqueries have less possibilities, older versions of mysql don't support it (don't know about more recent versions)*

Comment: I am down-voting you because I can't imagine a scenario where this would perform better than a join.  Frankly, this just reads like really bad advice.